# POM is missing, no dependency information available, cfg.xml not found

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, maven, orm

I've tried to connect my application with database as described on this site: https://www.visual-paradigm.com/tutorials/hibernateinnetbeans.jsp

I use MySQL and Maven project. But the rest is done the way it was explained on the website and when I run CreateAutoPartsStore I have such output:

```
The POM for unknown.binary:orm:jar:SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
```

[...]

```
--- exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) @ AutoPartsStore ---
org.hibernate.HibernateException: /ormmapping/AutoPartsStore.cfg.xml not found
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.ConfigHelper.getResourceAsStream(ConfigHelper.java:173)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.getConfigurationInputStream(Configuration.java:2026)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:2007)
    at org.orm.PersistentManager.<init>(PersistentManager.java:72)
    at autopartstore.AutoPartsStorePersistentManager.<init>(AutoPartsStorePersistentManager.java:31)
    at autopartstore.AutoPartsStorePersistentManager.instance(AutoPartsStorePersistentManager.java:41)
    at ormsamples.CreateAutoPartsStoreData.main(CreateAutoPartsStoreData.java:65)
```

This is my pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>AutoPartsStore</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>unknown-jars-temp-repo</id>
            <name>A temporary repository created by NetBeans for libraries and jars it could not identify. Please replace the dependencies in this repository with correct ones and delete this repository.</name>
            <url>file:${project.basedir}/lib</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>unknown.binary</groupId>
            <artifactId>orm</artifactId>
            <version>SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
</project>
```

I found some solutions to the problem concerning copying XML files to another location, but none of them worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to add hibernate jar to the Maven dependecies list.

This:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>unknown.binary</groupId>
        <artifactId>orm</artifactId>
        <version>SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

informs maven that your repository contains the artifact `unknown.binary:orm:jar:SNAPSHOT` but it seems it was never installed, and obviously is not present in Maven Central to be downloaded. What is it expected to point to?

Note that .jar lying around in folder marked as Maven repository does not make it count as installed. Also, Maven does not understand the notion of "Jar directory" and will not automatically add to classpath every jar from `lib` directory, if it is not declared as dependency.